# How to implement TypeScript Isolation in Blazor Components?

Tags: typescript, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, isolation

I know how to implement [JavaScript isolation in Blazor components](https://www.meziantou.net/javascript-isolation-in-blazor-components.htm).

```
// Use the module syntax to export the function
export function sayHi(name) {
    alert(`hello ${name}!`);
}
```

And

```
private Task<IJSObjectReference> _module;
private Task<IJSObjectReference> Module => _module ??= JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/demo.js").AsTask();

async Task Submit()
{
    var module = await Module;
    await module.InvokeVoidAsync("sayHi", name);
}
```

But how do I implement an isolated **TypeScript** connection in the Blazor components to call the "sayHi" function defined in the **TypeScript** file?

The problem is that if I export a function from a TypeScript module, like this:

```
export function sayHi(name) {
    alert(`hello ${name}!`);
}
```

Then it is compiled to the following javascript, which does not have " export":

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.sayHi = void 0;
function sayHi(name) {
    alert("hello " + name + "!");
}
exports.sayHi = sayHi;
//# sourceMappingURL=say.js.map
```

That's why I have this question. How do I implement an isolated **TypeScript** connection in the Blazor components to call the "sayHi" function defined in the **TypeScript** file?

---

**Answer**: Set module in compilerOptions to ES2015 or ESNext
[image]

Comment: Remove the wrapping module, why do you need it? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgGYFcB2BjOBLKaEDOAhgJ4AS2AFGkQLYgCUCA3sAuwkQDYjyUAGACxBcuUBABJmNegF8AhPwYBuYLKA

Comment: @AlekseyL., thank you for the answer, but how exactly do I do this on the Blazor framework? How exactly can I configure compilation in a project so that the resulting JavaScript remains "export"?

Comment: Set `module` in `compilerOptions` to `ES2015` or `ESNext`

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am having the exact same issue.  "export" in compiled TS gets omitted, and my WASM code can't then see the JS function to call.

Comment: @elyl, yes.See the previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `module` in `compilerOptions` to `ES2015` or `ESNext` – [Aleksey L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l)